# Django Rest Framework Serializer not respecting filter limit

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to filter the last message of a chat with the following query but the serializer ignores my selected set and prints out the entire result set.

When running the filter query in shell I get the correct number of results. I suspect it has something to do with the serializer only taking the base queryset because the order_by is not respected either. Which is pretty weird because the filter is respected.

```
    messages_obj = models.Message.objects.filter(chat__uuid=id).order_by('-sent')[:1]
    messages = MessageSerializer(data=messages_obj,many=True,read_only=True)
```

Comment: what does your view look like?

Comment: what is the result of **`len(messages.data)`**?